# NAD83 to NAD83(CSRS) transformation for Northwest Territories, Canada

Tags: coordinate-system, datum, canada

I am looking to determine the correct Grid Shift Binary (gsb) file for transforming data from the NAD83 original to NAD83(CSRS) geodetic datum for the NWT in Canada. I was able to find reference for a NAD83-98.gsb file for this purpose for Quebec, and I believe I saw another for Ontario, and other provinces, but nothing for NWT.

Comment: Would this one for entire Canada be useful for you? https://open.canada.ca/data/en/dataset/b3534942-31ea-59cf-bcc3-f8dc4875081a

Comment: @HansErren reviving old comments on an old question, but I have some more insight on this now, and figured I'd share. The GSB file you link to here is for transforming from NAD 1927 to NAD 1983 (Original), using the NTv2 grid-shift transformation; not for a NAD 1983 (Original) to NAD 1983 (CSRS).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unlike some other provinces (see list in answer comments). There is no specific transformation from NAD 1983(Original) to NAD 1983(CSRS) specific to the Northwest Territories, or to Canada as a whole. I have used the assumption that the differences between NAD 1983(Original) and NAD 1983(CSRS) are negligible (*Figure 2.*,Craymer, 2006) for specific areas.

Craymer, M. R. (2006). [The evolution of nad83 in canada](http://www.naref.org/transf/nad83_geomatica2006.pdf). GEOMATICA, 60(2), 151-164,433.

Comment: The following is a list of province-specific NTv2 GSB files available.

https://webapp.geod.nrcan.gc.ca/geod/tools-outils/grids.php?name=GRIDSELECTOR&datalist=suggestions_gridSelector

Comment: The names in the list are useful but the links in the don't lead anywhere

Comment: Thank you for the Geomatica article. The graphics for CSRS v7 at https://webapp.geod.nrcan.gc.ca/geod/tools-outils/nad83-docs.php indicate there are now more differences since NAD83-Original. That said I haven't found any resources yet for Original-to-CSRS in the North.

Comment: @mattwilkie the list is for this tool https://webapp.geod.nrcan.gc.ca/geod/tools-outils/ntv2.php

Thanks I should've added this.

Comment: I fleshed out the info from these links into a general answer for most canadian CSRS questions at https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/304398/nad-1983-to-nad-1983-csrs-transformation/. Thanks rgmrtn.